# How does the Nikkor 85mm compare to the Zeiss or G-Master 85mm on a Sony A7?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, sony, comparison, 85mm

Has anyone used both the Nikkor 85mm 1.4 and either the Zeiss Batis or Sony G-Master on a Sony A7?

I've been trying to find comparisons of it and the 85mm G-Master or 85mm Batis. Obviously the Nikkor won't have autofocus but image quality wise how does it compare? Also build quality do you think the Zeiss or G-Master will still be a great lens in 10+ years from now?

I love using my older lenses but for paid portrait work I'm debating if I should buy a used Nikkor 85 or invest in one of the newer 85's.

Answer (score 1):

One note, the Zeiss Batis is f/1.8 while the G master and Nikkor is f/1.4, so Batis is if nothing else a bit slower.

My guess will be, although I don't know, the Batis is sharper than the other two.

As to the Nikkor not having AF, well is all about using a smart adapter. You can get this smart adapter if you wish AF with your Nikon lenses on E-mount:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/172118708706?rmvSB=true